# Program template for printing *any* string

Tags: code-golf, source-layout

Write a program with the following properties:

- When run as-is, the program produces no output (i.e. 0 bytes of output).
- There is a location within the program (of your choice: it could be at the start, end, or somewhere in the middle) with the following property: modifying the program via placing *any* string there will cause the resulting program to print that string when executed.

  This must work regardless of whether the string contains quotes, backslashes, comment marks, delimiters, NUL bytes, etc.; no matter what you place there, the string is still interpreted as a string and printed entirely verbatim. You can, however, fail to handle very very long strings if they would cause the compiler to run out of memory, or the like (to be precise, you should at least be able to handle strings up to 1000 bytes long or three times the length of your program, whichever is longer).

An example of an *invalid* solution would be

```
print("");
#      ^ text goes here
```

in Python, Perl, Ruby, etc.; although it works for many strings, it will not work for a string containing a double quote, or a string containing the substring `\n` (which would be interpreted as a newline).

Note that this problem is probably impossible in most languages; the challenge is at least partially about finding a language where it works. Your chosen language must be a programming language under [this site's definition](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2073/62131), e.g. no submitting a solution in [Text](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Text).

As this is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), the shortest program template wins. However, do not be discouraged from submitting solutions even if they can't beat the current winner! You can still compete for second, third, etc. place, or simply to find as many answers where it works as possible. You should, however, ensure that your program meets the entire specification before submitting it; approximate solutions would miss the point of the problem.

Comment: The relevant Sandbox post is [here](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/10654/62131).

Comment: Can you clarify the range of characters we need to support for the inserted string? ASCII? ASCII + unprintable? All of unicode?

Comment: All 256 octets. Whether you interpret those as bytes or Unicode is up to you; it won't make much difference when it's printed.

Comment: When outputting the string, does it have to be only the string that's output or can there be extra stuff (along the lines of `this is the string: '<string_here>'`)?

Comment: The intent of the question (and the way it's currently worded) is that you can't have any additional output. Did you have a solution in mind that can't be adapted to avoid it? (Using extra bytes to avoid stray output is preferable to creating stray output and not complying with the spec.)

Comment: My idea was to write a program that doesn't print anything, but adding any string makes it output `syntax error: '<string_here>'` when run. ;p I guess I'll try to think of something else...

Comment: I suspect that doesn't work because syntax errors tend to stop at newlines rather than printing the whole of the rest of the program source. Interesting idea, though.

Comment: Newlines are allowed in ruby strings, and I think python strings as well. Just to be pedantic.

Comment: That's why I didn't specify newline as a character that would break. Rather, the two characters backslash, `n` break in the example because they're incorrectly interpreted as a newline.

Comment: @jimmy23013 Well, I don't know. Can you prove that it's impossible? It *seems* impossible, but I'm not 100% sure. (If replacements weren't done in a loop, it would be as simple as `//\\/`.) If you're sure it's impossible then we might as well delete the comments.

Comment: @MartinEnder Let S be the first matched string, A be a character different from the first and last character of S. A len(S) times cannot be changed by the first replacement. Let X be A len(S) times concatenated with S, and Y be the result of the first replacement applied to X. Y cannot contain S, so applying the first replacement to it yield itself too. Prefixing a string won't make a difference either, because of the A len(S) times part. X and Y would be indistinguishable afterwards.

Comment: If the string will never have either of these characters `｢｣` that will be as simple as `print ｢｣` in [Perl 6](https://perl6.org).

Comment: Do trailing newlines count?

Comment: You should aim to reproduce the trailing newlines of the strings. You're trying to make a byte-by-byte copy of them.

Comment: If this didn't require a code change, it'd be trivial in `AWK`, just `1` would do it.

Answer (score 37):

### Excel, 1 byte

```
'
```

Ungolfed version

```
'        <-- print the following text,
             and exit the current formula
```

Comment: I don't think this can accept newlines.

Comment: @ConorO'Brien it does with shift+enter

Comment: @MrPaulch This was quite a lot of retro engineering. I am pretty sure this command hides some other unknown functionnalities, like crashing the system.

Comment: This also works on OpenOffice Calc. It is used automatically when you set a cell to the format `@`.

Comment: Personally I think this answer is fine.  @Dennis deleted my Mathematica post which uses the same concept.  The front end of excel will store test // " "" /// as a non-verbatim string so by his logic, this should be deleted.  Here is how it's stored    <Row>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String" x:Ticked="1">test // &quot; &quot;&quot; ///</Data></Cell>
   </Row>

Answer (score 20):

## Jolf, 6 bytes

```
a Lq6(
```

### Explanation

```
a Lq6(
a       print
  L 6   all but the first 6 characters of
   q    the source code
     (  and exit
```

Answer (score 14):

## Zsh, 6 bytes

```
<<'
'
```

There is a trailing newline. The string is inserted at the end of the program.

## Bash, <del>20</del> 17 bytes

Thanks to [Adam](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/62418/adam) for removing 3 bytes.

```
exec sed 1d "$0"
```

## *nix shell script, <del>21</del> 14 bytes

Thanks to [Adam](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/62418/adam) for removing 7 bytes.

```
#!/bin/sed 1d
```

Comment: @Copper *There is a trailing newline.* The string is inserted after that.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for correcting me!

Comment: The 6/9-byte solutions look like they're exploiting a bug in the interpreter to me (not that that's disallowed, of course). (AFAICT with some experimentation, they're looking for a newline on a line by itself, but the lines are defined by splitting on newlines, so a newline on a line by itself can never happen.) The `zsh` solution seems correct; however, the 9-byte `bash` solution is wrong (it adds a trailing newline if the file doesn't have one).

Comment: @ais523 Seemed to be a bug to me too. And I didn't expect them to be allowed by the interpreters. Removed the Bash solution.

Comment: for bash you can use `sed 1d` instead of `tail -n+2`

Answer (score 14):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), <s>30</s> <s>21</s> 19 bytes

```
print<DATA>__END__
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@gKDOvxMbFMcTRLj7e1c8lPv6/kkdqTk6@ko5CeX5RTooil6ad3X8A)

Trailing newline. This makes use of a Perl feature which allows arbitrary data to be appended to the source file, which can then be read via the `DATA` filehandle. When we give a filehandle as an argument to `print`, it's given a list context, which causes the filehandle to return a list of all the lines in the file, newlines included (likewise, a newline on the final line will be omitted). Then `print` implicitly concatenates them all, undoing the splitting into lines and giving us the exact original string regardless of where the newlines were.

Thanks to @Dada, who realised there was no need to handle newlines manually, and @ninjalj and @b_jonas, who each spotted a character which could be golfed off.

Comment: I don't think you need `undef$/`. As an argument of `print`, `<DATA>` is called in list context, so it should read every line there is.

Comment: You're right. It reads the input a line at a time, keeping the line separators, then implicitly concatenates them all when printing, so there's no need to slurp in the first place. That's an 8-byte saving, as well; I'll go fix the post.

Comment: You can use `__END__` instead of `__DATA__`.

Comment: What @ninjalj says, plus you can omit the newline after the greater than sign (but you do need the newline at the end of the program).

Answer (score 13):

## brainfuck ([Unreadable Brainfuck](http://esolangs.org/wiki/User:Marinus/Brainfuck_interpreters#Unreadable)), 9 bytes

```
,+[-.,+]!
```

Append the input to the end. There isn't a trailing newline, this time.

Looking for languages which would accept input appended to the end of the program, brainfuck seemed like a distinct possibility; many brainfuck interpreters written in esolangs take both the program and the program's input from standard input, and thus need some way to tell between them. There's a convention that's used in this case that a `!` character differentiates between the program and the input, a trick that's often used to write short brainfuck programs like `,[.,]!Hello, world!`; this basically creates a different dialect of brainfuck in which `!` has a different meaning from normal.

In theory, therefore, we could just find one of these interpreters and give it a `cat` program in order to fulfil the spec. There's a major subtlety, though; brainfuck typically uses 256 values for each cell, there are 256 octets, and one needs to be used for EOF. So if we want to be able to echo all 256 octets literally, we can't detect EOF at all and will need to end the program some other way. In other words, we need to find an implementation that either gives the 256 octets and EOF 257 different values, or that crashes on EOF.

Enter [Unreadable](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Unreadable). There's a brainfuck interpreter in Unreadable that predates this challenge, and which accepts input after an `!`; additionally, unlike most brainfuck interpreters, it uses bignum cells and -1 for EOF, allowing EOF to be distinguished from the other 256 possible octets. Thus, by use of Unreadable Brainfuck as the specific interpreter for the program, we can solve the challenge in just 9 bytes, via writing a brainfuck `cat` program that halts on EOF=-1.

Is it possible to do better? Well, we could try the following 7-byte program, which attempts to *output* EOF at the end of the string before it breaks out of the loop:

```
+[,.+]!
```

The behaviour of this program depends on the behaviour of the Unreadable interpreter on error conditions (thus, it depends not only on the implementation of brainfuck, but on the implementation used to *run* the implementation of brainfuck). Unfortunately, the Unreadable interpreter I use outputs errors on standard *output*, meaning that this saving doesn't work. If anyone knows of an Unreadable interpreter that exits on an attempt to output EOF, or silently skips the attempt, let me know; that would be a seven-byte solution right there.

Comment: `,[.,]!` works [here](https://fatiherikli.github.io/brainfuck-visualizer/) and is 6 bytes (just tick the box marked `!`). Also it terminates.

Comment: @FinW: I can't figure out how to enter a NUL byte into that website, but that code would definitely terminate early if it saw one.

Comment: it worked fine without a NUL byte when I did it.

Comment: You literally have a `,` (read standard input to the current tape element) followed by a `]` (exit loop if current tape element is 0). Thus, reading an input byte with value 0 (i.e. NUL) would break the loop.

Comment: But if the interpreter reads no input, (e.g. the end of the string after the `!`) it automatically sets the current tape element to 0, therefore ending the loop.

Comment: Yes, and if it reads a NUL that isn't the end of the input, it also sets the current tape element to 0, therefore ending the loop. You not only have to handle exiting at the end of the file; you also have to handle *not* exiting *not* at the end of the file.

Answer (score 9):

## [Dyalog APL](http://goo.gl/9KrKoM), 11 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)

The following is the body of the function *f*:

```apl
2↓⎕CR'f'⋄→
```

There is a trailing newline, after which anything may be inserted.

`2↓` drop the first two lines (header and this line) of

`⎕CR'f'` the **C**haracter **R**epresentation of *f*

`⋄` then

`→` quit

Answer (score 9):

## Ruby, 20 bytes

```
print *DATA
__END__
```

Input goes at the end (after the trailing newline). The `DATA` idiom is one of many that Ruby [stole from Perl](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100934/11261).

Try it on eval.in: https://eval.in/684370

Comment: It not only stole it, it even is shorter...

Answer (score 9):

## JavaScript + HTML5 DOM, 163 Bytes

```
<html><body><script>fetch(location).then((r)=>r.text().then((t)=>console.log(t.slice(145,t.lastIndexOf("</b")))));document.body.remove()</script></body></html>
```

You may insert anything you like directly before the closing body tag. This works by fetching the page source and stripping the opening code and the closing tags.

The real kicker was figuring out how to escape an infinite loop. Putting `while(true){}` in the page blocks all callbacks forever, freezing the execution, and JavaScript has no way of pausing the main thread. However, code that no longer exists never runs, so the document body commits seppuku in the very last command, deleting itself while it waits for its clone to load.

Yeah, it's long and roundabout, but the mere fact that it's possible in JS is kind of amazing.

Comment: Chrome's got all annoyed at parser-blocking scripts recently, and complains about them a bunch. I like the idea of blocking the parser *intentionally* to prevent any script in it from ruining your printing attempt.

Answer (score 7):

## PHP, 46 bytes

(including the trailing linebreak)

```
<?=join([""]+file(__FILE__));halt_compiler();
STRING HERE
```

Yes: even the `file` function is binary safe.

`[""]+` replaces the 0-index (first line of the file) with an empty string

Answer (score 6):

## [gs2](http://github.com/nooodl/gs2), 4 bytes

```
╥¶=☼
```

Uses CP437 encoding. The string goes at the end. `╥` gets the source code, `¶` pushes 4, `=` drops that many leading characters, and `☼` exits.

[Try it online!](http://gs2.tryitonline.net/#code=4pWlwrY94pi8SGVsbG8sIFdvcmxkIQohQCMkJV4mKigp&input=)

Answer (score 5):

## PHP 94 bytes

```
<?$f=fopen(__FILE__,'rb');fseek($f,93);while(false!==($c=fgetc($f)))echo$c;__halt_compiler();
```

Place your string after the final semicolon.

Yay for obscure features I guess? __halt_compiler() does exactly what you'd expect from the name. The prior code just opens the file and writes any bytes after that last semicolon to stdout. NUL, BEL etc come out fine. Unicode literals (♪) get screwed up on Windows but I think that's just Windows cmd failing at unicode.

Comment: 1) I count 93 bytes, not 94.
2) `false!==$c=...` needs no parentheses.
3) `rb` needs no quotes.
4) You can save one byte with `for($f=fopen(...),fseek($f,88);false!==(...);)echo$c;`
5) another two bytes shorter:
`<?for($f=fopen(__FILE__,rb);false!==$s=fgets($f,86);)echo$i++?$s:"";__halt_compiler();`

Comment: 6) and another two bytes if you omit the second parameter for `fgets` and add a trailing linebreak to the template.

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 23 bytes

```perl6
print $=finish
=finish
```

The string is placed starting on the newline after `=finish`.

Answer (score 3):

## PHP, <s>48</s> 60 bytes

```
<?=substr(file_get_contents(__FILE__),60);__halt_compiler();STRING HERE
```

Just became aware that closing PHP does not prevent the string from containing `<?`.

Comment: You've got a misplaced closing bracket. Much neater file dump than my attempt though, I thought substr() would choke on null bytes - guess not.

Comment: Try this: `<?die(substr(file_get_contents(__FILE__),48))?>STRING HERE`. Should work. I've tried with [`<?die('a')?>`](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/99bd2cfdd457d1f33adfa052dee01bc52578ef56) and it worked.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel will not work. `die` does not print it´s parameter, but send it as exit code. That would have to ´be `die(print ...)`.

Comment: @ToXik-yogHurt most string functions are binary safe. even `file`. Actually I currently can´t think of any that´s not.

Comment: @Titus Try `die('text');`

Comment: I know I'm repeating myself, but `die()` outputs text. It was used a lot like `mysql*_connect(...) or die('Error while connection to DB');`

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel It may, but it won´t stop the compiler from parsing.

Comment: Oh, you changed your answer. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

## Bash, 17 bytes

```
tail -n+3 $0
exit
<string here>
```

Developed independently of [jimmy23013's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100933/41088).

Comment: Don't you mean `$0`? Apart from that, I think it works (I've confirmed that it doesn't parse anything after `exit`).

Comment: @ais523 Fixed! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

## [Binary Lambda Calculus](https://tromp.github.io/cl/cl.html), 1 byte

```
 [text goes here]
```

That’s a single space (0x20) before the text.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8pJ/v/fAAqsFIwMTCwUzEzNkhXMks3SFIySjQwUzM2BLHMjkJiJkaECFHik5uTk6yiU5xflpCj@/w8A)

#### How it works

0x20 = 00100000<sub>2</sub> is parsed as

```
00    λx.
01        x
0000  (ignored, can be anything)
```

(So in fact, any of the characters `!"#$%&\'()*+,-./` will work equally well.)

Since this is a complete expression, the remainder of the program is interpreted as input data, and under the binary lambda calculus I/O conventions, the identity function λ*x.* *x* copies the input directly to the output.

Comment: Out of interest, why don't the trailing zero bits between the identity function and insertion get echoed?

Comment: @ais523 The interpreter reads a byte at a time, and once λ*x*. *x* has been parsed, the padding has already been consumed.

Answer (score 1):

## [RProgN](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/Reverse-Programmer-Notation), 19 Bytes

```
Q 19 Q L sub exit
```

Note the trailing space.

Insert any text after that chunk and it will be printed.

Based off of [Lynn's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/3852/lynn) [gs2 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100979/58375).

[Try it Online!](https://tehflamintaco.github.io/Reverse-Programmer-Notation/RProgN.html?rpn=Q%2019%20Q%20L%20sub%20exit%20Hello%2C%20World!&input=)

Answer (score 1):

## Excel VBA, 6 Bytes

This is mainly to answer the question of how to print the text as held in [Adam's Answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/101023/61846) to the Immediates Window in the VBA environment

### Basic Setup:

In cell *A1* in the activesheet the use the formula below to hold the string to be printed. *For the sake of byte counting this shall add 1 Byte*

```vb
'[Your Text Here]
```

eg:

```vb
'Hello 
World
```

### Immediates Window Function, 5 + 1 = 6 Bytes

```vb
?[A1]
```

+1 Byte for a `'` in cell A1

Answer (score 0):

## Vim (in ex mode), 28 bytes

```
#!/bin/ex -c ':1d' -c ':wq'
[string]
```

28 bytes is including the last newline.

Answer (score 0):

## Vim, 738 bytes

```
:imap <esc> <c-v><esc>
:imap <c-a> <c-v><c-a>
:imap <c-b> <c-v><c-b>
:imap <c-c> <c-v><c-c>
:imap <c-d> <c-v><c-d>
:imap <c-e> <c-v><c-e>
:imap <c-f> <c-v><c-f>
:imap <c-g> <c-v><c-g>
:imap <c-h> <c-v><c-h>
:imap <c-i> <c-v><c-i>
:imap <c-j> <c-v><c-j>
:imap <c-k> <c-v><c-k>
:imap <c-l> <c-v><c-l>
:imap <c-m> <c-v><c-m>
:imap <c-n> <c-v><c-n>
:imap <c-o> <c-v><c-o>
:imap <c-p> <c-v><c-p>
:imap <c-q> <c-v><c-q>
:imap <c-r> <c-v><c-r>
:imap <c-s> <c-v><c-s>
:imap <c-t> <c-v><c-t>
:imap <c-u> <c-v><c-u>
:imap <c-v> <c-v><c-v>
:imap <c-w> <c-v><c-w>
:imap <c-x> <c-v><c-x>
:imap <c-y> <c-v><c-y>
:imap <c-z> <c-v><c-z>
:imap <c-@> <c-v><c-@>
:imap <c-\> <c-v><c-\>
:imap <c-]> <c-v><c-]>
:imap <c-^> <c-v><c-^>
:imap <c-?> <c-v><c-?>
i
```

Rebinds all control characters in insert mode to `<c-v>`, followed by that control character, which will enter them literally.
^_ (unit seperator) doesn't seem to need rebinding, as it gets outputted literally by default.

The variable text comes at the end, of course.